# Selenium WebDriver - Java - Click a button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click some buttons and I'm using the Follow button on twitch as an example.

I used the Selenium IDE to try to get the xpath for the button. What I got as xpath was: `//span[@id='ember637']/a/span`

If I go to FireFox and copy unique selector for the button I get: `.js-follow > span:nth-child(1)`

I have tried both in the java program and they don't work. When I use the `//span[..` xpath I get the following error:

```
"Unable to locate a node using //span[@id='ember637']/a/span"
```

Edit:

Example of a site with a button I want to click(The Follow button):
http://www.twitch.tv/mradder89/profile/

The Selenium jar file I am using is "selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar"

The error I am getting is

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using //span[@id='ember637']/a/span"
```

Edit 2:

I downloaded the PhantomJSDriver exe file(phantomjs.exe) and was trying it out. It doesn't work...
I do not get a error message like before(the 'Unable to locate a node...' error).

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/GzvubMZr

Comment: Edited my post with more info. I'm using "WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();" so no browser is being opened.

Comment: Wanted to add that it did click the Follow/Unfollow button when I used the Selenium IDE with target as "//span[@id='ember637']/a/span". Which is why I was suprised that it didn't work in the java program.

Comment: Try other browsers, if it works, then timing issue or issues with `HtmlUnitDriver`. So we can get back to solve it.

Comment: @user1177636 What do you mean try other browsers? The Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin

Comment: FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, InternetExploerDriver, etc.

Comment: @user1177636 FirefoxDriver DID work. It opened a firefox browser, went to twitch, logged in and followed/unfollowed a channel.I want it to work in the background though(Like HtmlUnitDriver).

Comment: Looks like something with HtmlUnitDriver, have you used [WebDriverWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)? Or try PhantomJSDriver, which a headless driver.

Comment: @user1177636 I do not use a WebDriverWait but I do a "Thread.sleep(3000) after the driver.get(...username/profile/) and THEN do the click. I do not know what a headless driver is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38359/discussion-between-user1021085-and-user1177636)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PhantomJSDriver, try different locators. Post exceptions if there are any, otherwise post the elemenst's info, e.g. location, text, etc.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'profile-actions')]//span[text()='Follow']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".profile-actions .primary_button > span")).click();
```