# Selenium Webdriver-Unable to interact with any element in the webpage

Tags: interaction

i am trying to click on the button links in the webpage http://stage.pressrun.prod.europe.s3.amazonaws.com/preprod/appstudiowidgets/index.html#issue/idmlintegration/landscape/1 but not able to do so.

Can anyone please provide the webdriver code in clicking any of the links in the page.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084041/selenium-webdriver-java-click-a-button

Comment: Still cant interact with the elements in the page.

Comment: driver.findelement(By.xpath(//*[@id='u477'])).click() to click the image in the slideshow is not working to take one example.