# Not able to click on a button in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
webDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.ignitionone.com/company/careers/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();        
Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/a/button")).submit();
```

'View positions' button is not clicking with the above code.What is happening in the web page?

Comment: Please edit the question with the error that you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

You see the HTML for this page is

[image: HTML]

So, you can use the CSS selector for this as

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.ignitionone.com/company/careers/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();        
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.teal").click();`

And then proceed with doing whatever is necessary. I executed with this in my Python code and it works fine.

Also, you will need to provide the Gecko executable path while calling for the `FirefoxDriver()`

Comment: Below worked for me .Thankyou. driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.teal").click();

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it before is to use the click handler.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".profile-actions .primary_button > span")).click();
```

I'm sure you could also select the element by xpath rather than CSS in the above line. It's a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084041/selenium-webdriver-java-click-a-button?rq=1).